# Links in $\mathbb R^3$ up to continuous isotopies.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

It is well-known that any knot in $\mathbb R^3$ is isotopic to the unknot, if we are in the continuous category, i.e. if isotopy is only through continuous embeddings. This is so because the "knotted" part can be continuously shrunk down to a point.

What do 2-component links reduce to in this category?

It seems if one tries to shrink the knotted part of one component, the second component would interfere (assuming it is not a split link).

Comment: Every *tame* knot is isotopic to the unknot. I don't think it's known yet for wild knots. You should still be able to reduce this to a bunch of linked unknots.